# List of Material Properties

Tags: materials

Blender materials have different properties such as "Specular", "Strand", "Ramp", "Diffuse", "Scattering" and etc. I am Blender newbie and I guess there should be a list of ALL material properties with short descriptions so one can figure out influence of each property on material behavior.

Could anybody advise where can find such list?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hi, here is a link to the blender docs for the principled BSDF, all other nodes and their properties are explained in the docs as well! https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/shader/principled.html

Comment: And if you want, here are [All 80+ Blender material nodes explained in under 30 minutes](https://youtu.be/cQ0qtcSymDI) :).